# WPF binding automatically to the first collection item

Tags: wpf, collections, binding

Is it the intended behavior that a binding to a collection automatically uses the first item as source?

Example Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ListSelection.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColContent}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemContent}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;


namespace ListSelection
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MyCol("col 1")
            {
                new MyItem("item 1"),
                new MyItem("item 2")
            };
        }
    }

    public class MyItem
    {
        public string ItemContent { get; set; }

        public MyItem(string content)
        {
            ItemContent = content;
        }
    }

    public class MyCol : List<MyItem>
    {
        public string ColContent { get; set; }

        public MyCol(string content)
        {
            ColContent = content;
        }
    }
}
```

The UI shows up with:

*col 1*

*item 1*

The second binding took implicitly the first collection item as source! So bug, feature or intended?

EDIT: .net 4.5, VS2012, corrections

EDIT 2:
I further investigated the problem together with a mate and got closer to the solution:

```
<Window x:Class="ListSelection.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemContent}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemContent}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The - lets call it - magic binding seems to exist for master detail views. By default any collection that is bound gets a CollectionView - which provides a selected item property (and other cool stuff like sorting). This selected item can be used shortcutted for the detailed view. If the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem is set to true the shortcutted binding reacts to changed selections. The problem in the whole thing: the selected item of the CollectionView is alway set to the first item which leads to the magic binding... I would call that a bug and it should only work explicitly, e.g. by binding the collection to a Selector with the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem set.

Comment: Woops I renamed that (my test hack was qick&dirty), doesn't change the weird binding feature...

Comment: If you try to data bind to a collection without providing an indexer, then you cannot be sure what you will see in the UI. Quite often, you would see the `Type.FullName` value of the relevant type. Use proper data binding paths to be sure what you will see. Also, data binding a collection property to a `TextBox.Text` property is also pointless... why would you do that?

Comment: There is some weird behavior an the question is not how to bind but why there is that behavior :)